# any mobile browser not support MaxLength attriute for input text field?

Tags: html, browser

We have a web site with a text field as , it works most of the time, but there are few cases which users are able to send data more than 20 chars to the backend, which causes some error.
I knew the validation should be done at server side, but can anyone tell how can this happen? I don't think the user(s) are using bots or firebug or scripts to manipulate the input html.
I tested most of the desktop broswer, the maxlenth works for all.
so the question is any mobile browser not support MaxLength attriute for input text field?

Answer (score 0):

You have a good chance that are browser bots
that make GET, POST request depending on your
code. MaxLength is supported by all browsers, however
beware! It is not supported by all browsers for textarea. Cheers.